# Drag drop in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make drag drop functionality in javascript. I have almost completed this but problem comes when `mousemove` event is fired. The element does not comes at pointer's location. I tried a lot of things but could not set it right. Here is the [link of my code](http://codepen.io/iiison/pen/OPjJKz). I am mentioning my code structure here too:

HTML:

```
<div class="pillers">
  <div class="dragable">Randome tet</div>
  <div class="dragable">Randome tet</div>
  <div class="dragable">Randome tet</div>
  <div class="dragable">Randome tet</div>
</div>
<div class="pillers"></div>
<div class="pillers"></div>
<div class="pillers"></div>
```

JS:

```
var mouseX = 0,
    mouseY = 0,
    elmX   = 0,
    elmY   = 0,
    tempZ  = 0,
    currentElm;

$(document).on('mousedown', '.dragable', function(e){
  var temp;
  $(this).addClass('abs');

  mouseX = e.clientX;
  mouseY = e.clientY;

  temp = +($(this).css('left'));
  //temp = $(this).offset().left;
  elmX = null || isNaN(temp) ? 0 : temp;

  temp = +($(this).css('top'));
  //temp = $(this).offset().top
  elmY = null || isNaN(temp) ? 0 : temp;

  $(this).css({'z-index':'9999'});

  currentElm = $(this);

  document.body.focus();
  // prevent text selection in IE
  document.onselectstart = function () { return false; }; 

  // prevent IE from trying to drag an image 
  $(this).ondragstart = function() { return false; }; 

  // prevent text selection (except IE) 
  return false;
}).mouseup('.dragable', function(e){
  if(currentElm !== null){
    currentElm.css({'z-index' : '1'});
    currentElm = null;
  }
}).mousemove('.dragable', function(e){
  if(currentElm !== null){
    currentElm.css({
      left : (elmX + e.clientX - mouseX)+'px',
      top : (elmY + e.clientY - mouseY)+'px'
    });
  }
});
```

The Dragging item is not setting its position properly. Here is the [Link for Codepen](http://codepen.io/iiison/pen/OPjJKz)

One more thing... what should be the condition if I want to check if mouse target is `pillers` class at `mouseup` event.

Comment: You would have done your live a lot easier with using the JQuery UI Draggable Function! YOu should have a look at it

Comment: Or even droppable http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#photo-manager

Comment: I know that.. but I want to do it with JS or max JQury.

Comment: Look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gigyme/YNMEX/132/

Comment: @rafaeldefazio what did I miss.. I will really appreciate dat.

Comment: somebody please help...

Answer (score 0):

The positioning of the element is not declared correctly in the mousedown event's function; they're always zero, above.

Because those values are the declared starting coordinates of the element, on mousedown, the element goes to the top left of the screen (0,0).

The elmX and elmY portions of the above could be replaced with the following:

```
elmX = $(this).offset().left;
elmY = $(this).offset().top;
```

This allows the starting coordinates to be the actual starting location when the mousedown occurs.

This change is working for me, in Chrome. An updated [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bNMbGg).